# Buying chocolate transfer sheet

Tags: food-safety, chocolate

I've just found my new-found love for making chocolate cups. And on one of the videos of how to make chocolate cups, the lady used a chocolate transfer sheet to get a really pretty chocolate cup, which she then filled with some mousse.

I wanted to buy some chocolate transfer sheets myself and started to look on ebay and found a lot of very beautiful sheets at very good prices. Before I go ahead and buy them, my question really is if they are safe to use (health-wise) and if I need to be aware of any issues with them, for example, should I only buy brown ones and avoid any that use colours.

Here are some pictures of them.

[image: Chocolate transfer sheet 1] [image: Chocolate transfer sheet 2] [image: Chocolate transfer sheet 3] [image: Chocolate transfer sheet 4]

Comment: If you consider food dye safe (as present in soft drinks, commercial ice cream, Skittles, and thousands of other products), then you should consider these sheets safe too, they are printed with food dyes. If you are afraid that officially approved dyes are bad, or suspect that the cheap sheets are a grey import from a country where there isn't enough quality control to ensure the use of approved dyes only, you shouldn't use them - we have no way to tell if this is the case.

Comment: @rumtscho: Then is there a brand that I can trust or are there things that I should be looking out for more?

Comment: sorry, I don't use them personally, so I can't recommend brands. But with the question here, I hope that somebody from the community will be able to tell you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are safe for three reasons:

1. They are approved by the food safety organizations.
2. You work the chocolate at a very low temperature.
3. You transfer the chocolate very rapidly.

Even with 'unsafe' plastic, nothing bad would happen.

Comment: I think the OP is more worried about the transferred pattern being unsafe, not about the plastic leeching anything.

Comment: @rumtscho, I guess you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You must ask hearlth certificate approval for transfer sheet, plastic food contact FDA approval test, and food colouring authorized in your country. Many compagny made transfer sheet with out license, and you don't really don't know what are inside... Make correct choice, and work safe on your creativity.. 
DECOTATOO.